# How to translate "The Dreams that Stuff is Made of " into Chinese?

Tags: translation

"The Dreams That Stuff Is Made Of" is the title of a book written by Stephen Hawking. I can't find any translation of the name of this book.

Here is the last page of the introduction of this book. The last paragraph may help you to understand the meaning of the name of this book.

[image]

Comment: web search: The Dreams That Stuff Is Made Of 中文 -＞ https://plus.google.com/110896187168631282520/posts/AVZDUTYodhk  Such stuff as dreams are made of = 夢所構成的東西？ (梦所构成的东西)

Comment: I'd go for something simple and succinct - **萬物之幻**. 幻 is broad enough to mean change/uncertain/illusion/dream/mysterious/imaginary, at least some of which are used in physics, and 萬物之幻 just means *The 幻 of all Creation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because no one has given an *actual* translation yet, I'll have a go at it.

The [巨星陨落，留芳人间](http://www.xue63.com/toutiaojy/20180316G0XS6W00.html) page gives us:

> [image: potatoe]

and the original text:

> 《梦想的构成》
>
> The Dreams That Stuff Is Made of: The Most Astounding Papers of Quantum Physics and How They Shook the Scientific World (2011)
>
> 这本书是现代重要物理学家作品的选本，包括波尔，普朗克，海森堡等的作品。

The list of Hawkins' other books on that page are all **official** Chinese translations of his books, there is no reason to think that this is not either.

**tldr;《梦想的构成》**

Comment: That's not a very good translation, and I think whoever tried to translate it got quite confused. **夢想的構成** is *The stuff that dreams are made of*, not *The dreams that stuff is made of*.

Comment: @droooze Closest thing I could find to an already translated title.

Answer (score 1):

> From Google Translates
>
> The dreams that stuff Is made of = 这些东西是由这些梦想组成的

"东西是由这些梦组成的" (literal translation)

or

"**物质**是由这些**幻觉**组成的" / "**物質**是由這些**幻覺**組成的" = "Matter is composed of these hallucinations" (descriptive translation)

Answer (score 1):

Title translation: 源物之梦

Explanation: 这些物来源于这些梦

Answer (score 1):

‘The Dreams That Stuff is Made of’  is a deliberate misquote of Prospero.

Prospero:
Our revels now are ended. These our actors,
As I foretold you, were all spirits, and
Are melted into air, into thin air:
And like the baseless fabric of this vision,
The cloud-capp'd tow'rs, the gorgeous palaces,
The solemn temples, the great globe itself,
Yea, all which it inherit, shall dissolve,
And, like this insubstantial pageant faded,
Leave not a rack behind. We are such stuff
As dreams are made on; and our little life
Is rounded with a sleep.

The Tempest Act 4, scene 1, 148–158

If we translate thus:

1.We are such stuff  as dreams are made on;
1. 由梦想编织成的我们，
2.  and our little life is rounded with a sleep.
2. 到头来不过以一场觉结束我们短暂的一生。

then we can just take 1. and insert 世界

The Dreams That Stuff is Made of
由梦想编织成的世界 (for 世界 understand 'space-time continuum, 时空连续统)

Comment: I love this translation and I upvoted this, but someone found an official translation so I accepted that answer.